# Defining math functions in zsh?

Tags: zsh

This is almost definitely a duplicate but I cant find a post with what I'm looking for.

I mainly use bash for work but I occasionally use zsh as a floating point calculator. While the `zsh/mathfunc` library is all well and good for `sqrt`, `sin`, etc., I wish to define other math functions within zsh, such as `pow`, such that they function thusly:

```
zsh% print $((pow(4.0, 4.0) + 1.0))
257.0
```

(Yes, I know about the built-in `**` operator, this is just an example)

The closest I have gotten to this is to use something like `print $(($(pow 4.0 4.0) + 1.0))` using functions as demonstrated by laviande22 but this is headache-inducing.

**Note:** I am not looking for an answer that gives the answer when the command is typed within bare zsh, such as `zsh% pow 4 4`. I am looking for a function that can be used within the math subsystem in the form given, i.e. `zsh% print $((pow(4.0, 4.0)))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`functions -M mathfn` could rescue. It defines a mathematical function, so we can use a arithmetic-style function calling expression such as `mathfn(arg,...)`.

```
my-powi () {
  res=1
  for ((i=0; i<$2; i++))
    ((res = res * $1))
  return res
}

functions -M pow 2 2 my-powi

echo $((pow(4, 4) + 1))
# >> 257
```

Here is the zsh document:

> `functions -M [-s] mathfn [ min [ max [ shellfn ] ] ]`
>   ...
>    `functions -M` mathfn defines mathfn as the name of a mathematical function recognised in all forms of arithmetical expressions; see Arithmetic Evaluation. By default mathfn may take any number of comma-separated arguments. If min is given, it must have exactly min args; if min and max are both given, it must have at least min and at most max args. max may be -1 to indicate that there is no upper limit.
>   ...
>   For example, the following prints the cube of 3:
>
> ```
> zmath_cube() { (( $1 * $1 * $1 )) }
> functions -M cube 1 1 zmath_cube
> print $(( cube(3) ))
> ```
>
> --- [zshbuiltin(1), `functions`, Shell Bultin Commands](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-functions-1)

Comment: This works but is somewhat clunky for redefining functions, though this is less of a problem since math functions tend to always do the same thing. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

How about defining functions in your `.zshrc` file, or importing another shell scripts that contain function definitions into your rcfile?

For example, you can write a function in `.zshrc` like this:

```
# In ~/.zshrc

function pow() {
    res=1
    for i in {1..$2};
        res=$((res * $1))
    echo $res
}
```

Then you can issue commands like `pow 2 4` which will echo 16. Zsh loads anything in rcfile when you start the shell, so you don't have to start off by defining all the functions you need to have every time. If you're not familiar with the syntax of zsh or bash, you may want to google it. Or maybe you can start from this [bash cheat sheet](https://devhints.io/bash).

You can also make a new script file and include it in rcfile.

```
# In ~/.zshrc

if [ -f ~/.custom_functions ]; then  # The file name is arbitrary.
    . ~/.custom_functions
fi
```

Comment: Ive seen this answer and this helps but isn't quite what I'm looking for. I have edited my question to hopefully be more clear